# Reducing process time of two map using c++

Tags: c++

I have two maps: Pkt_creatingmap and Pkt_arrivalmap. The number of elements in (Pkt_creatingmap) map is much more than the number of elements in (Pkt_arrivalmap) map [i.e.: total number of elements in Pkt_creatingmap about 650000 elements and total number of element in Pkt_arrivalmap about 72000 elements]. 
I want to compare the key IDs (firsts) in (Pkt_creatingmap) map and (Pkt_arrivalmap) map. If it is equal then subtract the values of key IDs (seconds) and store the result in list (TotalTrafficETED). 
I write below code to do this task, However it takes a long time to accomplish (i.e.: it is time consuming). Not all elements in (Pkt_creatingmap) map are needed in this process. The process of subtraction depends only on the elements of (Pkt_arrivalmap) map. 
Is there method to reduce the running time? (i.e.: can the iterator of (Pkt_creatingmap) map end at the end location of (Pkt_arrivalmap) map iterator?
Hope my question is clear.
Anyone can help me please or give me another ideal to do this task ..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<double_t, double_t> Pkt_arrivalmap;
    map<double_t, double_t> Pkt_creatingmap;
    list<double_t> TotalTrafficETED;
    int pos, pos2, pos3;
    double_t ArrivingID, CreatingID, ArrivingTime, CreatingTime, Pkt_ETED, TTETED;
    string line, search, word1 = "ns", word2 = "Pkt_create", word3 = "Pkt_recv";
    ifstream inf;
    inf.open("123.txt");
    if (inf.is_open()) {

        while (getline(inf, line)) {

            if (line.find("Pkt_recv") != string::npos) {
                pos = line.find(word1);
                pos3 = line.find(word3);
                line.replace(pos, word1.length(), "  "); // to remove "ns"
                line.replace(pos3, word3.length(), "  "); // to remove "Pkt_recv"
                istringstream iss(line);
                double_t column1;
                //double_t column3;
                double_t column2;
                iss >> column1 >> column2;
                //cout << column1 <<"  "<< column2 <<"  "<< " "<< endl;
                Pkt_arrivalmap[column1] = column2;
            }
        }

        inf.close();
    }

    else
        cout << "Unable to open file inf \n";
    for (std::map<double_t, double_t>::iterator it = Pkt_arrivalmap.begin(); it != Pkt_arrivalmap.end(); it++) {
        cout << "Arrival info."
             << "  " << it->first << "  " << it->second << "  " << Pkt_arrivalmap.size() << endl;
    }

    inf.open("123.txt");
    if (inf.is_open()) {

        while (getline(inf, line)) {

            if (line.find("Pkt_create") != string::npos) {
                pos = line.find(word1);
                pos2 = line.find(word2);
                line.replace(pos, word1.length(), "  "); // to remove "ns"
                line.replace(pos2, word2.length(), "  "); // to remove "Pkt_create"
                istringstream iss(line);
                double_t column1;
                //double_t column3;
                double_t column2;
                iss >> column1 >> column2;
                //cout << column1 <<"  "<< column2 <<"  "<< " "<< endl;
                Pkt_creatingmap[column1] = column2;
            }
        }

        inf.close();
    }

    else
        cout << "Unable to open file inf \n";
    for (std::map<double_t, double_t>::iterator it = Pkt_creatingmap.begin(); it != Pkt_creatingmap.end(); it++) {
        cout << "Creating info."
             << "  " << it->first << "  " << it->second << "  " << Pkt_creatingmap.size() << endl;
    }

    for (std::map<double_t, double_t>::iterator it = Pkt_arrivalmap.begin(); it != Pkt_arrivalmap.end(); it++) {

        ArrivingID = it->first;
        ArrivingTime = it->second;
        //cout << "Ahmed" <<"  "<< ArrivingID <<endl;
        for (std::map<double_t, double_t>::iterator it = Pkt_creatingmap.begin(); it != Pkt_creatingmap.end(); it++) {
            CreatingID = it->first;
            CreatingTime = it->second;
            if (ArrivingID == CreatingID) {
                Pkt_ETED = (ArrivingTime - CreatingTime) / 1000000000;
                TotalTrafficETED.push_back(Pkt_ETED);
                Pkt_creatingmap.erase(it->first);
                Pkt_arrivalmap.erase(it->first);
                cout << "Pkt_ID:" << CreatingID << ","
                     << "Pkt_ETED:" << Pkt_ETED << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    for (std::list<double_t>::iterator it = TotalTrafficETED.begin(); it != TotalTrafficETED.end(); it++) {
        TTETED += *it / TotalTrafficETED.size();
    }
    cout << "Total Traffic ETED"
         << "  " << TTETED << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You state that your basic task is to compare the keys in two maps. Then you proceed to post a bunch of bizzarely-indented code that does not appear to have anything to do with the task at hand. The code does something that involves reading from files, apparently; and something to do with lists. Yes, there are certain properties of maps that can be used to compare their keys efficiently, but this code's a mess. You need to either restate your problem succintly, or completely remove all irrelevant parts of the code that have nothing to do with key map comparison.

Comment: You say it takes a long time to do the task and there can be many reason for this. First, you need to do some profiling to see where the bottleneck is. Also, it seems that the order of the keys doesn't matter. If so, then you can use `unordered_map` (amortized constant lookup complexity) instead of `map` (logarithmic lookup complexity).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find an element with a given ID in a map, the method [map::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/) is very efficient and proceeds logarithmic in size of the map, because it is a sorted container. In your code, you do two for loop and the complexity is quadratic. Thus, you have to write something like that :

```
for (std::map<double_t,double_t>::iterator it = Pkt_arrivalmap.begin(); it != Pkt_arrivalmap.end(); it++)
    { 

     ArrivingID =it->first;
     ArrivingTime=it->second;
     //cout << "Ahmed" <<"  "<< ArrivingID <<endl;

     map<double_t,double_t>::iterator it2 = Pkt_creatingmap.find(ArrivingID);
     if (it2!=Pkt_creatingmap.end()){ // Found equivalent key

        CreatingTime=it2->second;
        Pkt_ETED=(ArrivingTime-CreatingTime)/1000000000;
        TotalTrafficETED.push_back(Pkt_ETED);
        Pkt_creatingmap.erase(it->first);
        Pkt_arrivalmap.erase(it2->first);
        cout <<"Pkt_ID:"<<CreatingID<<","<<"Pkt_ETED:"<<Pkt_ETED<<endl;
      }
    }
```